# What are the differents step that we have to go through when developing a website?

Tags: project-management

Web development is a mess.
This is because we have to interact with a lot of people.
Businness, Designers, Developpers, Leads, etc...

A website is a mixture of a lot of skills which involves programmers, designers, seo experts, business persons, ergonomists, etc...

So, the question is, how do you work to make all those people understand themselves, interact together.

How could I decompose the severals steps leading to a website ?

Because a lot of enterprise sales a design at first, how could you then add the right functionnalities ?

For example, we can decompose a project like this :

- Functional scopes (CRUD, Resources, ACL)
- Designing the interface
- Start development
- Write xhtml/css according to the interface with the functionnal requirements

I may have forgotten steps, or disordered them.

**EDIT :**

For example, here is how I do :

- I write a short overview about the project, what is the main goal ?
- I try to know which resources (users, articles, products, etc..) are involved.
- I write a short CRUD list for each resources which help me to have an overview about the features
- I start to design the database (with mysql Workbench for example)
- That done, i try to know if there are roles and privileges to rely them with the resources
- I start development (+ testing)
- Then i insert xhmtml code to respect W3C & web semantic.
- I start to insert visual design with CSS

So what about you ? what are you steps to be efficient ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

- Overall Site Intent
- User Analysis (Determine site/application Demographics, User Groups, etc.)
- Conceptual Design
- Graphic Design
- Functional Scope
- Interface Design (Prototype, Wireframes, etc.)
- Interface Mockups
- Development/Unit Testing
- User Acceptance Testing

...pick and choose the parts you need. Doing all of them may be overkill, but probably not if you're working on a large team with many groups giving their input. Making sure you don't miss steps gives a chance for everybody to give their input and decide on a course of action.

Answer (score 1):

Web development *is* different from other types of software development because frequently 
there aren't any users among the development personnel.  For example, "users" are absent from your list of people involved.

The users exist as a notional bunch of faceless people who are out there (we hope, because that's what the business plan is predicated on).  Requirements are gathered and design decisions taken on the basis of assumptions about what the putative users might like or want.

So in many ways web development more resembles opening a restaurant or launching a new political party than rolling out an ERP system.

Comment: Well, you are right, and in fact as i mentioned ergonomist, designers and functionnalites, i focused on the users, with the client requirement, of course.

Comment: I think ergonomists, designers, etc are professionals who have undoubtedly expert opinions about how users might interact with the system.  They are not users.

Comment: You are right, it's how users are considered until the final product. By the way, even experts, are users at first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's actually anything unique about web-development here compared to regular software development (with the exception of seo, which is just another technical challenge). I don't think there's anything inherently more "messy" about web-development. Read through the terms in your question again - do any of the terms (excluding seo as mentioned) not apply to general software development (substitute "xhtml/css" for "frontend development")?

Personally, I think any software engineering methodology which you've found works for your team-size/work environment/colleagues/etc is applicable to web-development.

There's nothing magical about the fact that the end-product runs in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

XP and Agile methodologies look at creating teams whose members have all the skills needed for the project, such as Project Manager, developer, business anylist, designer, tester etc.

Having teams means there is better comunication between everyone involed including the client.

The subject is massive so do some google searches on XP, agie, scrum, kanban.

Answer (score 0):

Yup dear you are right, there are several steps in developing a dynamic website however you want to develop a static site then its easy. 
the only designing is needed for it and some functionality is added by a designer like email and so on.
but if you are going to develop a dynamic website then its accomplished by these steps.
1. First you make sure about the requirement.
2. Then you decide about its interface and layout.
3. Designer designed all the Form the are needed
4. Then the developer./ programmers will add functionality on froms .
5. After Completing the coding part the project goes to Testing for erros.
6.if any error occurs then it rectified by programmer again it goes to testing this process will going on until all error has not been removed.
7. Finally the web site publishes and then hosted on a server.

Answer (score 0):

> A website is a mixture of a lot of skills which involves programmers, designers, seo experts, business persons, ergonomists, etc...

If you're really lucky you will have a team of talented multidisciplinarians who can take on more than one role.

That's when you tend to get the best web products.

Design by committee, which you will always get if everyone only gets to 'wear one hat', rarely produces kick-arse products.